# High contrast theme doesn't show some icons on the launcher

Tags: resolution, screen

I have lenovo r61 notebook. When I choose hightcontrast I can  not see some icons including the setings icon on the left side bar.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because the High Contrast Icon theme needs an update. Not all applications in use nowadays, are represented by the High Contrast icon theme. I have been updating the High Contrast icon theme a bit, but it is more a personal project. You can find more about that here: http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/Treepata+-+High+contrast?content=151928

Answer (score -1):

Try installing your display driver of you have a special one. Ubuntu 11 is little buggy with that crazy Unity thing.